# What is different between refresh method and redraw method in Kendo-UI chart?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I find the kendoui chart has two methods: `refresh` method and `redraw` method, what is the difference? I think both of them is to draw the chart again. But if the chart is binding from remote data according to ajax, the request will not fire again.

```
$("#Chart").data("kendoChart").redraw();
$("#Chart").data("kendoChart").refresh();
```

Answer (score 10):

[`redraw`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/dataviz/chart#methods-redraw) will render the chart again using the current data, which can be used when changing the size of the chart, for example. [`refresh`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/dataviz/chart#methods-refresh) will also rebind the data, so if your data source changed, this will be reflected.

Comment: I have a situation,at first I have a page which is to draw a chart with autobind from remote data,Now I want to add a line in this chart,it means I have to change the datasource( add the line data to the datasource),Which method should I use best?I find use refresh or redraw method are both OK.